# What happens when I make purchases on Amazon as a company but I don't register the VAT invoice?

Tags: europe, vat, hungary

I have a company in Europe.  If I use my Amazon business account to buy work related stuff,  I don't pay the VAT.

What would happen if I used my personal credit card rather than the company card  to buy non-work related items in my  VAT exempt account and I didn't have my bookkeeper record the VAT invoice?

For example, sometimes my wife accidentally uses the wrong account to order stuff.  Does Amazon send the invoice to my government in any case?